# PHP foreach loop stops unexpectedly while parsing data from SQL

Tags: php, foreach

I'm generating a table from MySQL data, looping through all keys from each row to generate the table headers. This foreach loop (line 6 below) stops after the 25th column in the table, even though var_dump($result) shows that the query has returned all 35 columns from the table.
The solution will probably cause major facepalms, but I just cannot get my head around this.

```php
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        while($thead_done == 0) {
            echo "<thead>";
            foreach($row as $rkey => $rvalue) {
                echo "<th>";
                switch($rkey) {
[bunch of cases to make the table headers human readable]
                    default:
                        echo $rkey;
                        $s_headers[]='"' . $rkey . '"';
                }
                echo "</th>";
            }
            echo "</thead>";
            $thead_done++;
```

To confirm that the issue was not with the contents of the 25th column in my database, I modified the SQL query to explicitly select this column, and it parses just fine.
Also, I am sure that PHP just stops inside the foreach loop, because the returned HTML ends with:

```html
<th>[column 25 header]
```

meaning the closing  tag on the last line of the loop was not echo'ed.

Unfortunately I don't have access to the PHP logs on this webserver, which makes it even harder for me to understand why it just halts at this position.

Update: I changed the start of the code ever so slightly, for debugging purposes, but it behaves the same. Full code:

```php
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        print_r(array_keys($row));
        while($thead_done == 0) {
            echo "<thead>";
            foreach(array_keys($row) as $rkey) {
                echo "<th>";
                switch($rkey) {
                    case "ppower":
                        echo "Plasma Power";
                        $s_headers[]="Plasma Power";
                        break;
                    case "cathodel":
                        echo "Cathode Length";
                        $s_headers[]="Cathode Length";
                        break;
                    default:
                        echo $rkey;
                        $s_headers[]='"' . $rkey . '"';
                }
                echo "</th>";
            }
            echo "</thead>";
            $thead_done++;
            /* Spout XLS GENERATION */
            $writer = WriterFactory::create(Type::XLSX);
            $writer->openToFile($filename);
            $style = (new StyleBuilder())->setFontBold()->build();
            $writer->addRowWithStyle($s_headers, $style);
        }
        unset($s_data);
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach($row as $rkey => $rvalue) {
            if($rkey == "magnet_id") {
                echo "<td><a href=\"details.php?id=" . $rvalue . "\">" . $rvalue . "</td>";
                $s_data[]=$rvalue;
            } else if($rkey =="edms") {
                echo "<td><a href=\"[URL here]" . $rvalue . "/1\" target=\"_blank\">" . $rvalue . "</a></td>";
                $s_edms = '=HYPERLINK("[URL here]' . $rvalue . '","' . $rvalue . '")';
                $s_data[]=$s_edms;
            } else {
                echo "<td>" . $rvalue . "</td>";
                $s_data[]=$rvalue;
            }
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        $writer->addRow($s_data);
    }
    $writer->close();
}
```

Also, printing all the keys of the $result array confirms that all the data is returned:

> Array ( [0] => magnet_id [1] => magnet_type [2] => origin [3] => scheduled_time [4] => vc_id [5] => removed [6] => removed_time [7] => ir1 [8] => coated [9] => coated_run [10] => coated_time [11] => system [12] => sey [13] => ir2 [14] => lastop [15] => edms [16] => pump_time [17] => pressurel [18] => ccomment [19] => bakeout [20] => duration [21] => pressure [22] => pvoltage [23] => pcurrent [24] => ppower [25] => cathodel [26] => pdensity [27] => modified_time [28] => reinstalled_loc [29] => reinstalled_time [30] => username [31] => sample_id [32] => rfqc [33] => rfqc_time [34] => rfqc_comment )

But the table still looks like this:

```html
<thead><th>Asset ID</th><th>Asset Type</th><th>Position</th><th>Scheduled</th><th>Vacuum Chamber</th><th>removed</th><th>Removed</th><th>ir1</th><th>Coated</th><th>Coating Run</th><th>Coating Time</th><th>Coating System</th><th>SEY</th><th>ir2</th><th>lastop</th><th>EDMS</th><th>Start Pumping Time</th><th>P-limit</th><th>ccomment</th><th>bakeout</th><th>Proc. Duration</th><th>Proc. Pressure</th><th>Plasma Voltage</th><th>Plasma Current</th><th>Plasma Power
:EOF
```

Comment: mysqli_fetch_assoc read one row and then go to the next. So you don't need to perform a foreach($row as $rkey => $rvalue). Just read $row['namecol1'], $row['namecol2'] and so on.

Comment: Please show the whole code.. probably you are changing something in the loop(s)'s variables

Comment: If it outputs `<th>[column 25 header]`, I would suspect the 26th column and some failure in the switch.

Comment: @Peter, thanks, but I can't use $row['colname'] here, because the query is dynamic, so I don't know which columns will be returned.

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus, it could indeed be the switch, but not the 26th column, as the code stops executing before finishing the loop for the 25th.

Comment: Can you post the whole code, meaning with all the closing } . Thanks

Comment: @Peter, done, updated in the question. I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: For getting the name of the field on the first loop, you must use foreach($row as $key=>$value) even if you just the $key. If you do foreach($row as $key) what you'll get in the $key is not the name of the row, but the value of the row. Also, rather than a while with thead_done I'll suggest a basic flag. Init eg flag_first=true before the loop and do an if(flag_first== true) get the key and end with flag_first = false. This would be easier to read.

Comment: Thanks again @Peter, that's good advice for writing better code.
After adding `ini_set("display_errors", "1");error_reporting(E_ALL);`
to the beginning of my file, I quickly discovered that the error was caused by a different part of the switch (as was suggested) changing the $s_headers array into a string, triggering an "Illegal operator" exception on the next iteration.